# How to connect a VM to the Internet in VMware vCloud using a Network Gateway CIDR

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-vcenter, cidr, vmware-vcloud-director

I am familiar with managing servers and VMs that have their own IP address and network connection, but am now trying to host a VM in a VMware vCloud and am a newb for this.

I have created the VM and configured its webserver and iptable Firewall, but now need to configure the network, as I cannot access it from the Internet.

I already have an Edge that has a subnet (.../24), ip address, Sub-allocated IP Pool (...134 - ...135), and a Default Gateway (...101.1)

I need to create VDC Network, from what I understand I need a "Routed network connecting to an existing edge gateway" and can select the exiting Edge.

Next I need to set the "Network Gateway CIDR" and I have no idea what to enter here?

Comment: Well it's your gateway plus the netmask - so aa.bb.cc.dd/24 or whatever - that's what's meant as CIDR format, that's all it'll mean.

Comment: okay, thanks, so I enter the value of "default gateway" /24 or /23

Comment: Probably yeah, IP and netmask in that format